# Jmeter throws "socketexception: connection reset" error during execution

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

The target for us to achieve is 500 concurrent users.
We have tried running a test for 100 users over 3 machines. And it ran fine without any errors.
When i tried running the test for 150 or More users with same number of machines, i started getting the following response code

Response code:Non Http Response code:java.net.socketException
Response message:Connection Reset

I have also tried increasing the number of machines to 8 machines. Still it is of no help. Response time is also very high (156 seconds) for some of the requests.

When we checked the server logs to find out what could be causing this issue, **No error logs were found** there during the time of the execution.

I'm having a hard time finding out what could be the issue. The server side is ruling out if there could be an issue from their end.

Tried the following fixes from Jmeter side:

1. Increasing the heap size
2. Changing the retry count in user.properties file
3. Changing Boolean=True in hc.parameters file
4. Used HTTP Request Defaulters to change the implementation to HTTPClient4

CPU Config:
Intel (R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60 GHz (2 Processors)
5 GB Ram
64-bit Operating System

Comment: Did you try to run your script from some cloud? i.e Blazemeter . That should give you more insights about what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The `Connection Reset` error means failed attempt to write to the socket which has been closed already, on TCP protocol level it means receiving a [TCP RST](https://www.pico.net/kb/what-is-a-tcp-reset-rst)

It might be the case JMeter is closing the connection prematurely as JMeter 5.0 had `httpclient4.time_to_live` property set to `2000` and if you're seeing response times > 2 seconds (and you do) most probably JMeter is closing the connection before getting the full response.

You can try increasing this setting to `60000` matches modern browsers default settings or even more to match your application response time (if you think 3 minutes is acceptable) or consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3/) which has better default value.

More information: [Bug 64289](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64289)

Comment: Hi dmitri, I am currently using Jmeter 5.3 and the default value is already 60000. Still the error persists. Is there an alternative solution for this?